# Select on 3 columns without duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns in SQL Server:

```
Article_Id   LanguageCode     Text
---------------------------------------------
    1           FRA           Sac en papier
    1           GER           Tragtasche
    2           GER           Pizzapapier
    3           FRA           Couteau
```

The result of the query would need to be:

```
Article_Id    LanguageCode    Text
-------------------------------------------
    1           FRA           Sac en papier
    2           GER           Pizzapapier
    3           FRA           Couteau
```

Every `Article_Id` only once and first `LanguageCode` is `FRA` and if not exist then GER

I tried with distinct but it didn't result right.

Comment: Does the 3rd column text matter? If it soes, then an answer involves a subquery at least (if keeping this simple)

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  With just two languages, I think the easiest method is:

```
select a.*
from atable a
where a.LanguageCode = 'FRA'
union all
select a.*
from atable a2
where a.LanguageCode = 'GER' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from atable a2
                  where a2.article_id = a.article_id and a2.Language_code = 'FRA'
                 );
```

If you have more than two languages, the above gets cumbersome.  So, use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by article_id
                                order by charindex(languagecode, 'FRA,GER')
      from atable a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `charindex()` is a short-cut so you don't have to write a long `case` statement.  As written, it should be fine if we assume that all language codes have the same length.

Comment: Tragically, you might be assuming there is no relation to the text.

Comment: @clifton_h . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  This returns the `text` column with the highest priority language.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with distinct but it didn't result right.

`DISTINCT` removes duplicate *rows*.  You want to remove duplicate `Article_Id`s and show the "first" row for each one.  So start there:

```
select Article_Id, min(LanguageCode) as LanguageCode
from T
group by Article_Id
```

To get rows in table *A* matching rows in table *B*, use `EXISTS`:

```
select * from T as main
where exists (
    select 1 from T
    where Article_Id = main. Article_Id
    group by Article_Id
    having min(LanguageCode) = main.LanguageCode
)
```

You can get there with a join, too, by joining your table to the first query, but being comfortable with correlated subqueries will save you work over time.